# Plants near bonsai

Tags: trees, bonsai

Few weeks after using a fertiliser, couple of plants started to grow near the tree. Can someone recognise what kind of plants they are? Should I remove them?

Thanks[image]

Comment: Is this one of those "supermarket bonsai" that typically show up every Christmas? I'm guessing that way because of the pebbles.

Comment: On the left is some species of Oxalis- lives happily with most plants.